# Should I be sending Firebase ID Tokens via URL parameters to my NodeJS backend?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am currently using Firebase for authentication on my application. As per the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), I am sending an ID token to my NodeJS backend each time I need to make an HTTP request. On the server-side, I simply decode the ID token and use the relevant data.

My question is, **is it secure for me to send the Firebase token from my front-end to my server via URL parameters?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the HTTP request is performed through https:// type URLs, no one should be able to intercept the token.  It doesn't matter if the token is sent via query string or request body - the encryption between the client and server is the same.  If you trust the security of HTTPS, then you trust the security of any communication over that channel.

Comment: What if it's an img tag that the user might share the link?

Comment: @jacob Well, obviously, if you share the plain text of a URL, or any string for that matter, everyone will know what it contains.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes i was asking a leading question. My real question is what alternative approach to use in that case.

Comment: @jacob Why don't you ask a dedicated question here on SO rather than bury it in a comment?

Comment: What i’m doing is creating a custom token with claims on user ip, referrer domain, and user agent. I’m wondering what other people’s approach is.